# How to get persistence unit name from EntityManager

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

Is it possible to get the associated persistence unit name of an EntityManager object? For example, you have

```
@PersistenceContext( unitName="fooPU" )
private EntityManager em;
```

Is it possible to get the name `fooPU` from `em`? The motivation for this is that I want to have a small test to verify that the injected em through `@Inject` is associated with the right persistence unit.

Comment: From the top of my head, the properties of the EMFactory (`entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties()`) might contain the PU name

Comment: @kostja: Thanks. As a matter of fact, that is my current workaround, except that I don't have the `getEntityManagerFactory()`, i.e., I use `entityManager.getProperties()`, which gives the same property map as yours. But that map doesn't have a standalone PU name key. It does have the PU name embedded in some other keys, though. You can get the PU name with some hacking, but it just doesn't seem clean to me.

Comment: Yeah, clean would be different :) Unfortunately, I am not aware of a different way.

Comment: I know it's a bit old post but you can consider asking [JPA EG](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC) about providing such feature. If it's easy to add - why not try asking for it. If it's not possible because of some reasons it would also be nice to know why.

Answer (score 8):

the persistance unit name is under the key "hibernate.ejb.persistenceUnitName" in the properties Map

```
String puName = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().get("hibernate.ejb.persistenceUnitName").toString()
```

Comment: What if the JPA provider is not hibernate, like EclipseLink?